# Does the act of placing a bet make people much more confident in the outcome of a prediction?

Tags: psychology, marketing, persuasion

Robert Cialdini writes in his book Influence about a principle he calls "Commitment and Consistency":

> A STUDY DONE BY A PAIR OF CANADIAN PSYCHOLOGISTS (KNOX & Inkster, 1968) uncovered something fascinating about people at the racetrack: just after placing bets they are much more confident of their horse’s chances of winning than they are immediately before laying down the bets. Of course, nothing about the horse’s chances actually shifts; it’s the same horse, on the same track, in the same field; but in the minds of those bettors, its prospects improve significantly once that ticket is purchased.

Is this effect well replicated and well supported by the literature since 1968?

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice-supportive_bias